# What type of object is returned when keySet() method of HashMap is called in java?

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator

From the documentation, it returns `Set<E>` which is an interface. Suppose I write this,

```
Set<E> keys = myHashMap.keySet();
```

I do not understand what exactly is returned by this `keySet()` or what are the variable keys.

Also, why am I able to do this

```
Iterator<E> it = keys.iterator();
```

as interfaces do not implement any of its methods.

Comment: Please, read a basic Java book and don't miss the chapter about polymorphy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to java doc,

> Map.keyset() Returns a set view of the keys contained in this map. The
>   set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the
>   set, and vice-versa. If the map is modified while an iteration over
>   the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove
>   operation), the results of the iteration are undefined.

so basically it is an object of a class which implements Set Interface that's why we are able to call iterator() on that object.

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap.keySet()` returns set of the keys in the hash map.

```
HashMap<Integer, String> myHashMap = new HashMap<>();
myHashMap.put(1, "one");
myHashMap.put(2, "two");
myHashMap.put(3, "three");

Set<Integer> keys = myHashMap.keySet();
System.out.println("keys of the map are: "+keys); // prints [1, 2, 3]
```

Also, `Set<E>` extends `Collection<E>`, which also extends `Iterable<E>`. That means `Iterable<E>` is a superinterface of `Set<E>`  That's why you are able to do `iterator()` from `Set<E>`

Answer (score 0):

`myHashMap.keySet()` returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map `myHashMap`.

Remember that `Map` is different from `Set` such that:

1. `Map` consists of `key` and `value` pair. A `Key` is mapping to a specific `value`.
2. `Set` consists only on individual objects of any type. They aren't stored in pairs.

see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet()).

---

***What is an iterator then?***

If you will want to cycle through the elements in a collection, For example, you might want to display each element. In our case, if you want to display each key in the set that's returned, then we'd use the `iterator`.

> Iterator enables you to cycle through a collection, obtaining or removing elements.